# Reshaping a dataframe with multiple variables from wide to long

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, reshape

apologies if the same question has been posted elsewhere, but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I have a dataset from WDI that looks approximately like this:

```
country           iso3   variable name               1995    1996    1997 ...    2021

Afghanistan       AFG    "Infant mortality rate"      6.5      6.9      7        5.5
Afghanistan       AFG    "GDP growth"                   3        2      0.6      1.2
...
Albania           ALB    "Infant mortality rate"       5      4.2      3.2       2.1
Albania           ALB     "GDP growth"                 3        2      0.6       1.2

...
Zimbabwe          ZWE    "Infant mortality rate"       9       8.3      3.5       2.9
Zimbabwe          ZWE     "GDP growth"                 3.5     3.1      2.1       1.1
```

I would like to reshape this dataset in order to obtain something like this:

```
country           iso3     year      Infant mortality rate    GDP growth   

Afghanistan       AFG      1995           6.5                   3
Afghanistan       AFG      1996           6.9                   2
Afghanistan       AFG      1997           7                     0.6
...                         
Afghanistan       AFG      2021           5.5                   1.2
Albania           ALB      1995           5                     3
Albania           ALB      1996           4.2                   2
Albania           ALB      1997           3.2                   0.6
...
Albania          ALB       2021           2.1                    1.2
...
Zimbabwe          ZWE      1995           9                      3.5
Zimbabwe          ZWE      1996           8.3                    3.1
Zimbabwe          ZWE      1997           3.5                    2.1
...
Zimbabwe          ZWE      2021           2.9                    1.1
```

I tried to use `melt`, `reshape` and `pivot_longer` but with messy results.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your data is not easily usable, unfortunately, Can you please add the output from `dput(x[1:20,1:7])`?

Answer (score 2):

Usable sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
quux <- data.frame(country=rep(LETTERS[1:3],2), iso3=rep(letters[1:3],2), varname = rep(c("infant","gdp"), times=3), `1995`=sample(1000,6),`1996`=sample(1000,6),`1997`=sample(1000,6), check.names = FALSE)
quux
#   country iso3 varname 1995 1996 1997
# 1       A    a  infant  561  146  839
# 2       B    b     gdp  997  634  356
# 3       C    c  infant  321   49  601
# 4       A    a     gdp  153  128  165
# 5       B    b  infant   74  303  622
# 6       C    c     gdp  228   24  532
```

## tidyr

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(quux, -c(country, iso3, varname), names_to = "year") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = varname, values_from = value)
# # A tibble: 9 × 5
#   country iso3  year  infant   gdp
#   <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>
# 1 A       a     1995     561   153
# 2 A       a     1996     146   128
# 3 A       a     1997     839   165
# 4 B       b     1995      74   997
# 5 B       b     1996     303   634
# 6 B       b     1997     622   356
# 7 C       c     1995     321   228
# 8 C       c     1996      49    24
# 9 C       c     1997     601   532
```

## reshape2

(This also works using the `data.table::` functions if you're using a `data.table`.)

```r
reshape2::melt(quux, c("country", "iso3", "varname"), variable.name = "year") |>
  reshape2::dcast(country + iso3 + year ~ varname, value.var = "value")
#   country iso3 year gdp infant
# 1       A    a 1995 153    561
# 2       A    a 1996 128    146
# 3       A    a 1997 165    839
# 4       B    b 1995 997     74
# 5       B    b 1996 634    303
# 6       B    b 1997 356    622
# 7       C    c 1995 228    321
# 8       C    c 1996  24     49
# 9       C    c 1997 532    601
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
pivot_longer(data_frame_name, cols = `1995`:`2021`)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It keeps the infant and gdp values within their own column instead of breaking them into two (or more) columns as shown in the OP. (I think my `quux` is a decent-enough sample of the OP's question, perhaps you can try with that.)